# Passing Exception to custom Exception Handler Method. Java

Tags: java, exception, methods, parameter-passing

I have a class with about 20 methods which all catch 1 or more Exceptions and then respond to the user based on that Exception. Instead of writing them over and over again, I want to create a single method which is passed the Exception, handles it, and gives the appropriate response.

Here's an example

```
public boolean addFirst(Object data){

    try {
        //add something 
        return true;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        exceptionHandler(e);
        return false;
    } 
}
```

But when I try to compare it with "e" it gives me "*Exception* cannot be resolved to a variable".

```
private void exceptionHandler(Exception e) {
    if(e == UnsupportedOperationException) {
        System.out.println("Operation is not supported.");
    } else if (e == ClassCastException) {
        System.out.println("Class of the specified element prevents it from being added to this list.");
    } else if (e == NullPointerException) {
        System.out.println("You cannot enter nothing.");
    } else if (e == IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
        System.out.println("Your specified index is larger than the size of the LinkedList. Please choose a lower value.");
    } else if(e == Exception) {
        System.out.println("You messed up so hard that I don't even know what you did wrong."); 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does *"it doesn't like me treating the exception like a variable"* mean? Please add the compiler error or warning that is occuring.

Comment: Hey, sorry I wasn't very exact. Just fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E.g. `UnsupportedOperationException` is not a declared variable, this is what the compiler is complaining about.

When doing `e == UnsupportedOperationException` you are checking if the reference of `e` equals the reference of `UnsupportedOperationException` but `UnsupportedOperationException` was never declared.

To check the type of an object you have to use the `instanceof` keyword and the `class` you want to check against.

```java
e instanceof UnsupportedOperationException
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use instanceof instead of ==, because you're attempting to compare two different types.

```
if(e instanceof UnsupportedOperationException)
```

etc